# listdir of a network shared folder in Python

Tags: python, networking, operating-system, share, listdir

I have a network shared folder with file path `:C\\Local_Reports`. I would like to use `os.listdir(":C\\Local_Reports")`, but the output is `['desktop.ini', 'target.lnk']`. This is not the correct output obviously. The correct output would be `[Daemons, Reports, SQL]`. How do I successfully access this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm silly. I figured it out. I just took the target of the Local_Reports folder and wrote `os.listdir(r"\\03vs-cmpt04\Local_Reports")`. This just searched the network for the folder and listed the correct output: `[Daemons, Reports, SQL]`